# Formula for n+n a number of times

Tags: factorial

So I have a simple budgeting idea where I save N amount per week, and I add n again to what I save next week, and so on and so forth.

So on the first week lets say I save 4. Next week I save 8, and then 12, and then 16 etc etc. And I want to do this for let's say 52 weeks for a year.

What formula should I use to solve for how much I need to save on the 31st week?

Comment: It looks like you have an arithmetic sequence here ...

Comment: On the week number $k$, you need to save $kn$.

Comment: formula for sum of an AP is $S_n=\frac{n}{2}(2a+(n-1)d)$ here $n=52$, $a=4$, $d=4$

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar Make that an answer! It's a good hint and doesn't give too much to the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

formula for sum of an AP is $S_n=\frac n2(2a+(n−1)d)$ here $n=52, a=4, d=4$

Comment: Thanks for this one! Although this solves for how much money I would have saved after _n_ weeks. Not quite determine how much I should save in the bank on the _nth_ week itself